# pandas find if an ID exist in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Imagine i have a dataframe with ID1 and ID2

```
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize list of lists
data = [[1, 10], [2, 15], [10, 14]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID1', 'ID2'])
```

I would like to find if ID1 exists in ID2

so in this case the output should be

```
ID1,ID2,Exists
1,10,False
2,15,False
10,14,True
```

I followed the answers here

[Check if column value is in other columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093394/check-if-column-value-is-in-other-columns-in-pandas)

But the output is all True, which is not correct

```
df_test["exists"] = df_test.drop("ID1", 1).isin(df_test["ID2"]).any(1)
```

Could someone help?  In the environment is Python 3. Thank you

Comment: Just use `df_test['ID1'].isin(df_test['ID2'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.intersect1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html#numpy-intersect1d):

```py
intersection = np.intersect1d(df_test["ID1"], df_test["ID2"])
df_test["Exists"] = df_test["ID1"].isin(intersection)

print(df_test)
```

Prints:

```
   ID1  ID2  Exists
0    1   10   False
1    2   15   False
2   10   14    True
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I prefer the `transform` method.

```
df_test['exists'] = df_test['ID1'].transform(lambda x: x in df_test['ID2'].values)
```